# How to Concatenate or Merge columns in a jagged array of type object[][]

Tags: c#

I am having a jagged array of type object[][] with 10 rows and 5 columns. I want to merge last two columns into one (last but one column) and remove the last column.
For example:

Row 1 has below Columns

```
sampleData[0]  - "110"
sampleData[1]  - "ABC"
sampleData[2]  - "Google"
sampleData[3]  - "{object[2]}"
             [0] - "{object[3]}"
                 [0]  - "01"
                 [1]  - "apple"
                 [2]  -  "Fruit"
             [1] - "{object[3]}"
                 [0]  - "02"
                 [1]  - "Mango"
                 [2]  -  "Fruit"
sampleData[4]  - "{object[1]}"
             [0] - "{object[3]}"
                 [0]  - "03"
                 [1]  - "Banana"
                 [2]  -  "Fruit"

Now I want sampleData[4] to be copied to sampleData[3] and remove sampleData[4].
So it should be like below
Row 1:
sampleData[0]  - "110"
sampleData[1]  - "ABC"
sampleData[2]  - "Google"
sampleData[3]  - "{object[3]}"
             [0] - "{object[3]}"
                 [0]  - "01"
                 [1]  - "apple"
                 [2]  -  "Fruit"
             [1] - "{object[3]}"
                 [0]  - "02"
                 [1]  - "Mango"
                 [2]  -  "Fruit"
             [2] - "{object[3]}"
                 [0]  - "03"
                 [1]  - "Banana"
                 [2]  -  "Fruit"
```

Can someone suggest me how to achieve this?
Here is the code which I tried:

```
    public static object[][] MergeResults(object[][] sampleData)
    {
    
    object[] mergedArray, actualData;
    object[][]results;
    if(sameplData != null && samepleData.Any())
    {
    int row = 0;
    int totalNoOfColumns = sampleData[0].length;
    int noOfColumns = totalNoOfColumns; 
    results = new object[sampleData.Count()][];
    int objectCount = sampleData[0].Where(x=>x.GetType().Name == "object[]").Count();
    
        foreach(var item in sampleData)
    {
        mergedArray = new object[totalNoOfColumns -1];
        actualData = new object[objectCount];
        int j = 0;
        
        for (int i= 0; i < (item.Length - 1); i++)
        {
          if(item[i].GetType().Name == "object[]")
        {
        int k = 0;
        while (i < totalNoOfColumns)
        {
        actualData[k] = item[i];
        i++;k++;
        }
        mergedArray[noOfColumns- 2] = actualData;
        }
        else
        {
        mergedArray[j] = item[i];
        j++
        }
        }
        results[row] = mergedArray;
        row++;
        }
        }
        return results;
        }

I see the results for column 3 is coming as 
sampleData[3]         {object[2]}
            [0]       {object[1]}
              [0]     {object[3]}
               [0]   "01"
               [1]   "apple"
               [2]   "Fruit"
            [1]          {object[1]}
              [0]     {object[3]}
                [0]     - "02"
                [1]  - "Mango"
                [2]  -  "Fruit"
```

Here I want to avoid {object[1]} in every set.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please post code

Comment: FYI: Just to clarify terminology, a two-dimensional array would be `object[,]`. `object[][]` is called a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Comment: Seriously could have you not provided valid C# code for your data? Now to write up and test a solution we need to do that work. Could you please do it? And if the expected output could be as C# code too then we can properly test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the data in valid C# form:

```
var sampleData = new object[]
{
    "110",
    "ABC",
    "Google",
    new object[]
    {
        new object[]
        {
            new object[] { "01", "apple", "Fruit",  }
        },
        new object[]
        {
            new object[] { "02", "Mango", "Fruit",  }
        },
    },
    new object[]
    {
        new object[]
        {
            new object[] { "03", "Banana", "Fruit",  }
        },
    }
};
```

Then this works:

```
var output =
    sampleData
        .Take(3)
        .Concat(new object[]
        {
            sampleData
                .Skip(3)
                .Cast<object[]>()
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .ToArray()
        })
        .ToArray();
```

I wrote this formatter to test it:

```
IEnumerable<string> Output(string prefix, object data)
{
    if (data is object[] array)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (var x in Output($"{prefix}[{i}]", array[i]))
                yield return x;
        }
    }
    else if (data is string text)
    {
        yield return $"{prefix} = {text}";
    }
}
```

Now the `sampleData` is:

```
[0] = 110
[1] = ABC
[2] = Google
[3][0][0][0] = 01
[3][0][0][1] = apple
[3][0][0][2] = Fruit
[3][1][0][0] = 02
[3][1][0][1] = Mango
[3][1][0][2] = Fruit
[4][0][0][0] = 03
[4][0][0][1] = Banana
[4][0][0][2] = Fruit
```

And the `output` is:

```
[0] = 110
[1] = ABC
[2] = Google
[3][0][0][0] = 01
[3][0][0][1] = apple
[3][0][0][2] = Fruit
[3][1][0][0] = 02
[3][1][0][1] = Mango
[3][1][0][2] = Fruit
[3][2][0][0] = 03
[3][2][0][1] = Banana
[3][2][0][2] = Fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Copy the contents of sampleData[4] to sampleData[3]
sampleData[3] = sampleData[4];

// Remove sampleData[4]
sampleData.splice(4, 1);
```

Use this format in your code.